# Datos en Form Data se van vacios en la peticion |ANGULAR|

Tags: nodejs, angular, mongodb

Hol, estoy tratando de mandar ciertos datos en una peticion Post mediante angular, pero me encuentro con el problema que los datos llegan vacios :( La verdad no se porque, si anteriormente lo habia utilizado en otro service y los datos me llegan normal.

Este es mi metodo que envia los datos:

```
addProductToCar(product, user: CartItem) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('productId', product._id);
    formData.append('name', product.name);
    formData.append('price', product.price);
    formData.append('userId', user.userId);
    return this.http
      .post<CartItem>(this.URL + '/cart', formData)
      .pipe(map((res) => res));
  }
```

Y pues aqui esta el backend que recibe los datos, pero no entiendo porque sigo recibiendo el req.body vacio

```
cartController.addToCart = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const data = {
      productId: req.body._id,
      name: req.body.name,
      price: req.body.price,
      userId: req.body.userId,
    };
    const productExits = await model_product.findById(req.body._id);
    if (!productExits) {
      res.status(409).json({
        status: 'No se puede añadir al carrito porque el producto no existe',
      });
    }
    const product = new model_cart(data);
    const resultado = await product.save();
    res.json({
      resultado: resultado,
      status: 'cart add',
    });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

**UPDATE**

Esto es lo que recibo antes de hacer el post desde angular

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: buenas tardes.
Lo primero que me sale preguntarte es ¿Los datos a ese servicio llegan bien?
Podrías poner un `debugger` justo antes del `POST` para ver como quedó el objeto que envías. En el caso que no lleguen bien al servicio... ¿El objeto que se le manda al servicio está bien? No se de donde tomas esos datos, pero si es un formulario, tendrías que construir el objeto antes de mandarlo. Otra pregunta, ¿Donde estás aclarando que el endpoint está esperando un `POST`?

Comment: Otra aclaración útil, en mi caso me pasó cuando quise enviar una imagen, si pasaba los datos de mi componente a un `service` los perdía, en cambio si hacía el `POST` desde el componente la imagen la tenía, quizás podrías hacer eso solo para probar.

Me gustaría que nos proporciones esos datos para darte mas información.

Saludos

Comment: Hola, llegan perfectamente, tanto el objeto product, como el id del usuario, y no es un formulario, es un card donde se cargan los datos del producto. Pues a mi el servicio me ha estado funcionando bien con otros componentes, por ejemplo, a lo que te refieres con la imagen, siempre llegaba correctamente, ahora no entiendo porque no se envian dichos datos.

Comment: Pon un breakpoint en `return this.http...` y mira qué tiene `formData` antes de enviarse. Puede que no el objeto no se esté enviando correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Despues de pensar, se me ocurrio en vez de Form Data, usar un objeto, de esta manera y eso dio a mi solucion:

```
addProductToCar(product, userId) {
    const data = {
      productId: product._id,
      name: product.name,
      price: product.price,
      userId: userId,
    };
    return this.http
      .post<CartItem>(this.URL + '/cart', data)
      .pipe(map((res) => res));
  }
```

El Cart_Controller tuve que modificarlo, debido a que me lanzaba un error refiriendose a que no podia actualizar los headers luego de enviarlos al cliente.

```
cartController.addToCart = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const data = {
      productId: req.body.productId,
      name: req.body.name,
      price: req.body.price,
      userId: req.body.userId,
    };
    const productExits = await model_product.findById(req.body.productId);
    if (!productExits) {
      return res.status(409).json({
        status: 'No se puede añadir al carrito ',
      });
    } else {
      const product = new model_cart(data);
      const resultado = await product.save();
      res.status(200).json({
        resultado,
        status: 'Carrito Añadido',
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```